# How to tcpdump command in Python?

Tags: linux, shell, python-2.7

When I check 3331 port is using for transporting data or not, I use the command.

```
sudo /usr/sbin/tcpdump -n -X port 3331
```

I'd like to this command but I don't like to use subprocess.popen command.

Could you tell me the way that satisfy my requirements?

I tried to install pypcap.
But, error occurred.

```
 pip install pypcap
Collecting pypcap
  Downloading pypcap-1.1.1.tar.gz (44kB)
    100% |################################| 45kB 1.1MB/s
    pcap.h not found
    Complete output from command python setup.py egg_info:
    pcap.h not found

    ----------------------------------------
    Command "python setup.py egg_info" failed with error code 1 in /tmp/pip-build-MW1HMb/pypcap
```

I installed pcap-devel and installing pypcap was successfully.

Later I tried the script.

```
import pcap

for ts, pkt in pcap.pcap():
    print ts, `pkt`
```

But, OSError happened

```
Traceback (most recent call last):
  File "pypcap_test.py", line 3, in <module>
    for ts, pkt in pcap.pcap():
  File "pcap.pyx", line 189, in pcap.pcap.__init__ (pcap.c:1689)
OSError: no suitable device found
```

I should have Authority for tcpdump?

Comment: `tcpdump` is just a front end to `libpcap`. You may try to use something like [pypcap](https://pypi.python.org/pypi/pypcap)

Comment: you can also try yourself to bind to this port, if it works it means it's free...

Comment: You need to install the `libpcap` and `libpcap-devel` packages (or whatever your distribution calls them) before installing `pypcap`.

Comment: Error happened again....